# Hierarchy Level to display from than level down on SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

So I have a report with 4 parameters;

```
@LevelParameterCheat; Hierarchy Level, this is the level inside the cube
@DimOrganizationCustomerHierarchy; Organizational Level
@FromDimDateDateSK/@ToDimDateDateSK; used for filtering
```

Here is the DataSet MDX Query;

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY
{ (DESCENDANTS([Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].Levels(@LevelParameterCheat).ALLMEMBERS) ) }
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, LEVEL_NUMBER ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( 
STRTOSET("[Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].&[" + @DimOrganizationCustomerHierarchy + "]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date SK].&[" + Format(@FromDimDateDateSK,"yyyyMMdd") + "]", CONSTRAINED) :
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date SK].&[" +  Format(@ToDimDateDateSK,"yyyyMMdd") + "]", CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Portal Data Mart])) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

What I need: At time of execution the user knows his Org Level and dates to filter. The report needs to display all data from the selected Org Level down.

What I’m looking for; I need to somehow use the Org Level to query the cube and look for the specific level of the selected Org and plug it in the DECENDANTS Function so it displays only from that level on.

What I’ve done; ….ahhhhgggg to many trials and errors . The latest was to try and get the level doing something like this…

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.LevelNumber AS [Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].&[@DimOrganizationCustomerHierarchy].Level.Ordinal
```

And if that worked I assumed it would bring a numeric value of the level that I then have to concatenate with the DECENDANTS command, something like this…

```
{ (DESCENDANTS(STRTOSET("[Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].Levels(“level “" + LevelNumber + ").ALLMEMBERS)"))}
```

Well, something is not right because it doesn’t work. I’m very new to MDX and lacking on the syntax so if someone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it very much. So far the query above works on the report because I manually enter the Org/Level combination but the user would not know what their Level is. I’ve been at it for almost two weeks and need to fix this. I feel I’m close but not there yet. Please help

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

well here is the answer to the problem;

`SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Count] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY

**{ (DESCENDANTS(StrToMember( "[Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].&[" + @DimOrganizationCustomerHierarchy + "]",CONSTRAINED).Level.ALLMEMBERS) ) }**

DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME, PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME, LEVEL_NUMBER ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( 
STRTOSET("[Dim Organization].[Customer Hierarchy].&[" + @DimOrganizationCustomerHierarchy + "]", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( 
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date SK].&[" + Format(@FromDimDateDateSK,"yyyyMMdd") + "]", CONSTRAINED) :
STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Date].[Date SK].&[" +  Format(@ToDimDateDateSK,"yyyyMMdd") + "]", CONSTRAINED) ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Portal Data Mart])) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS`